# Is it possible to make a database file out of a project directory(containing C files)?

Tags: search, database, source-code

My requirement is to improve time for a pattern search (using `grep` or any other search tool) in a source code directory containing mainly C source files. I have a big code base that makes it difficult to search for text. I know I can use `cscope`, which makes it easy to search for symbols (function names/variable names) within less time, however `cscope` won't help in the case where we want to search a text string (e.g., a comment section). I would like to know if there a way to improve the pattern search time by making the source code directory a database that I can easily search?

Comment: How big (MB? GB?) is your source code directory? How long does a typical search take to run, and what's an example of a typical search?

Comment: You might take a look at  Opengrok: https://oracle.github.io/opengrok/.  If you have Docker, it's pretty easy to set up to run in a container.

Comment: @roaima. My source code directory is around 3GB. If I text search using cscope, it takes almost 5 mins, same with grep as well.

Comment: `ctags` (but no good for comments). Deploy an inverted index? Probably with that is that I would imagine many of your words are in many different source files, so the saving isn't going to be great. You also would have to consider the frequency at which you rebuilt the index. At the end of the day, adding faster disks and/or more memory to the system on which you do the searches may help. As will having the source code held locally to the search operator